Running Multiple Application Instances on Different Branches in IntelliJ - Potential Class Loading Issues?
I'm trying to understand how IntelliJ handles class loading when running multiple instances of a Java application on different branches.
When you run an application directly from the IDE (like IntelliJ), it doesn't create a Jar file but runs the built class files and resources directly, right?
Now, let's say I start my application on port 8080 from branch A in IntelliJ. Then, I checkout branch B and run the same application on port 8081.
When switching from branch A to branch B, the working directory changes according to the new branch.
The class files in my working directory would now correspond to branch B.
Since Java loads classes dynamically, it might not load all the classes initially but only when they are needed later.
Could there be a situation where, when the application tries to load a class later, it fails because the class files from branch A are no longer available due to the checkout to branch B?
I'm curious if this scenario could cause issues and how IntelliJ or Java handles such cases. Any insights would be appreciated!



"the working directory changes according to the new branch" -- no, the working directory does not change; it is the contents of the working directory that change.  I know that's what you meant, but keep in mind that in engineering, precise language is of paramount importance.

As you mentioned, IntelliJ doesn't generate .jar files until you make it to do so. It just compiles the .java files into .class files, and then runs them. When you switch to another branch and compile the program once again, the .class files will be overwritten. Then, running Java program will probably raise ClassNotFoundException or, if you are lucky, just use the updated version of class.
The solution that might be possible is to build the each version of solution you need to run explicitly into .jar files and launch them as normal .jar.

If you launch, check out, build, (thus overwritting .class files,) then launch again, you can get all kinds of errors. Besides ClassNotFoundException you can get ClassCastException, NoClassDefFoundException, etc. Heck, you could possibly even receive InvalidClassException or UnsupportedClassVersionError if one of your branches uses a different version of the SDK. In short, when you change the .class files under a running application, virtually anything can happen: bowls of petunias and sperm whales might fall from the sky.
One way to avoid this, as suggested, might be to configure your IDE to build a .jar file, (and to suffer the overhead of .jar file creation each time you build,) so that you can then be launching a .jar file. Unfortunately, if you try this, there is a possibility that when you check out your "other" branch and try to build, the .jar file might fail to be created, because it might be locked by the other instance of your application which is already running. Your tooling might even fail to notify you that it failed to create the .jar file, so you might think you are running two different versions of your application, while in fact you are running two instances of the same version. You do not want to be in this situation.
What I do in these cases, (and what I have seen others do,) is to have a separate source tree for each branch that I might want to have simultaneously checked out, and to launch a different instance of the IDE on each source tree.
So, I have the following directory structure:
MyApp
    MyApp1
         .git
         source code
         binaries
    MyApp2
         .git
         source code
         binaries

I use MyApp1 to check out some branch, and MyApp2 to check out some other branch. Note that the directories are not named after the branches, because the branches change all the time.
An additional benefit of doing this is that you can debug all simultaneously running instances of your application at the same time.
